# Many errors when compiling C# code

Tags: c#

I'm just learning C# and I tried to make a simple terminal game like thing. So, when I tried to compile it it gives out 6 errors.

The code is:

```
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, what is your name? :   ");

    string name = Console.ReadLine(); //Lets you enter the name

    Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}! What should I do? \n Type help for list of commands);

    Console.ReadKey();

    string command = Console.ReadLine();

    if(command == "help")
        Console.WriteLine("The only command for now is \"Market\"");

    else if(command == "Market")
        Console.WriteLine("You're now at the market");

    else
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I didn't understand you!");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And here's what the terminal says about it:

```
ReadLine.cs(24,70): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `The'
ReadLine.cs(24,100): error CS1056: Unexpected character `\0022'
ReadLine.cs(24,102): error CS1056: Unexpected character `\0022'
ReadLine.cs(24,105): error CS1010: Newline in constant
ReadLine.cs(26,39): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)'
ReadLine.cs(29,12): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `else'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One line has a missing closing quote, and looks to cause the other erros:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}! What should I do? \n Type help for list of commands);
```

Try this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}! What should I do? \n Type help for list of commands");
```

---

If you get an error which makes no sense to you and the line it refers to appears to be correct, this is often a sign of an error on a previous line. Have a look just above the lines with reported problems.

If you still can't see it, try commenting out a few lines to narrow down the problem.

Missing quotes and/or semi-colons are often culprits.

Comment: And to add to what @doctorlove said... often times a single error will generate multiple errors.  Fix one, and all (or many) go away.